# having trouble importing python module from root directory in PyCharm

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, python-import

Here is my folder structure:

```
lib\
    pt_hil\
        utilities\
            PT_HILdSPACE_Utils\
                exception\
                    __init__.py  --> has "class SimulatorException(Exception):"
                pythonScript.py
```

I opened the project from the "lib" folder in PyCharm. In the "pythonScript.py" script, when I try to import SimulatorException by doing:

```
from pt_hil.utilities.PT_HIL_dSPACE_Utils.exception import SimulatorException
```

It doesn't work. However if I do:

```
from exception import SimulatorException
```

It works. Shouldn't the root directory be from the lib folder? When I look in settings the content root is set to the lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the purposes of a `__init__.py` file, is to mark the directory as a valid Python package that you can `import`.

You only declared the `exception` folder to be a valid Python package and therefore that's the root package you can start importing from.

It's either you create top level packages by adding empty `__init__.py` files to each top level folder you have and then can import as you originally wanted, or keep the current structure and import directly from `exception` package.